# Найти корректно число старта xref таблицы в pdf документе

Tags: php, потоки-данных, pdf

Допустим у меня есть большой pdf файл версии 1.6. И в конце файла должна быть информация:

```
startxref
5638681
%%EOF
```

Благодаря которой, естественно, система знает положение начала xref таблицы пдфа. Но у меня там значится только:

```
startxref
56386
```

И естественно файл сыпется и везде не читается. Этот файл лишь как пример. Основной вопрос заключается в том - возможно ли как-то на лету пересчитать положение начала xref и проставить его(число) в нужном месте в конце файла, чтобы даже в случае ошибки она была исправлена и файл бы прочитался? Я поискал по документу и слово Xref, кроме конца в startxref, встречается только в самом конце документа, аж на 28164 строке, в потоке прямо перед концом файла и словом startxref. Получается как-то вот так:

<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[]/Info 81 0 R/Length 467/Root 83 0 R/Size 155/Type/***XRef***/W[1 3 1] вот в этом фрагменте:

```
154 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<A95E63F8E64607C01DE088DCA9B76927><A934A84176582B4C8931FAEC898E990B>]/Info 81 0 R/Length 467/Root 83 0 R/Size 155/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream
hЮ¬’1LSQ†П=ЇTh…гD\”(С   :tPг`Xl|qa`qRЌ@HCЦД'BЊ,jBd!Д°‡VЁ‰ў‰>ќФШ(¶Шw|зЬЮј6ДЌелџпю9чјж" 8ЂРHptьП9яє"~F!…їnђыкс‚ц€d§Z<ц/|_њz­Ѕ…tдД·љсї]WыТ±іy>ыпгЭЪ· uЅ-п™ѕ{бЅцa¤УwЖЄ¦яссeн!х\Я¬˜~юйOн[‘вгkЊПҐKЪ·!ќ+>Ъ5s2v\ыТEы|ЩфЯТЪG‘О¬пяjіюЅ‡‘’эЈЫfОвrBыv¤«gпmїђн“я •уБтНЛXНMя'-Y=Ђ[
у§uV•ЗќјХзouТjЮJ9_њ#“|ЪЩіoзыН3эi)Џэн-4E ~-аEдЮ’0,¦-0d3±Tп“уcKЮШ„LdZ]LUх©zу’‡˜xSr«4o3/eЕИ¶±њд‡Т\’Ь!Н»МДІ˜1IЙЙ z&чкУS|otКзьЮњ˜OТМЯ    WВКьЄдХ†УS?u…Эrы°d~3Ч*рOЂ ш…§±
endstream
endobj
startxref
56386
```

Я уже пыталя по советам с интернета подсчитать в байтах кол-во символов перед словом xref с начала файла, но там переваливает значение за 9 лямов, а мне надо ровно 5638681. Сам вес файла кстати 5 639 408 в байтах. Есть ли какие-то рабочие способы такого подсчета или может какие-то консольные утилиты, которым можно скормить файл и в ответ получить нужное значение старта xref?

Comment: А как количество символов перед xref может быть больше длины файла?